# Valid Parenthesis String - LeetCode

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was going through the question on LeetCode linked [here](https://leetcode.com/articles/valid-parenthesis-string/).

Given a string containing only three types of characters: '(', ')' and '*', write a function to check whether this string is valid. We define the validity of a string by these rules:

1. Any left parenthesis '(' must have a corresponding right parenthesis ')'.
2. Any right parenthesis ')' must have a corresponding left parenthesis '('.
3. Left parenthesis '(' must go before the corresponding right parenthesis ')'.
4. '*' could be treated as a single right parenthesis ')' or a single left parenthesis '(' or an empty string.
5. An empty string is also valid.

> **Example:**
>
> **Input:** "(*))"
>
> **Output:** True

I've gone through the methods specified in the article but I'm unable to understand **method 2** which is related to **dynamic programming**. Can anyone explain how do we need to approach the problem via dynamic programming? Thanks in advance!

Main pain point:

> or, s[i] can be made to be '(', and there is some k in [i+1, j] such that s[k] can be made to be ')', plus the two intervals cut by s[k] (s[i+1: k] and s[k+1: j+1]) can be made valid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much clearer we can make the explanation already offered in the LeetCode link you shared. The stated formulation for the dynamic program there is

```
Let dp[i][j] be true if and only if
the interval s[i], s[i+1], ..., s[j]
can be made valid.
```

First consider that any valid parenthetical construction can be reduced to a combination of self-contained valid sections, each one with their own left and right balanced ends. For example,

```
((()())())
```

has two inner sections at depth 1:

```
(valid_A valid_B)
  where valid_A is (()())
    and valid_B is ()
```

According to the problem description, a `*` can be made into an empty string. This would cover the first case in the dynamic program formulation,

```
dp[i][j] is true if:
  s[i] is '*', and the interval
  s[i+1], s[i+2], ..., s[j]
  can be made valid
```

since we would be looking at an already valid, or "self-contained," section of the input, from `s[i+1]` to `s[j]`, and adding nothing (an empty string) to it.

The second case for validity is if `s[i]` can be `(`, or the start of a valid section, in which case, if we can identify its specific balancing closing parenthesis, `)`, at `s[k]`, the two sections we can now identify would have to each be valid in order for the whole section to be valid. To take the former example,

```
((()())())
 i    k j
```

and use the language you have shared:

```
if s[i] can be made to be '(',
and there is some k in [i+1, j] such
that s[k] can be made to be ')'
```

which we have:

```
(()())()
i    k j
```

"...plus the two intervals cut by `s[k]` (`s[i+1: k]` and `s[k+1: j+1]`)..."; where `s[i: j]` means the interval `s[i], s[i+1], ..., s[j-1]`.

```
()() -> that's i+1...k-1

and

()   -> that's k+1...j
```

"...can be made valid;" then the whole section `s[i..j]` is valid.

Comment: Oh, it was notation s[i:j] that was actually confusing me. Thought both the indices (i and j) are inclusive. Thank you!

P.S.I've edited the answer to add that clarity.